# Easily calculate the inverse of a probability distribution function

Tags: python, optimization, statistics, probability, distribution

I am trying to simulate a large number of numbers generated by a certain probability distribution. Due to the large number of generations, the code is extremely slow and uses all my RAM.

If I use the normal distribution to generate the numbers, with `scipy.stats.norm.ppf(random.random())`, the code is executed easily, which is why I know that the problem comes from this.

The only way I thought of was to create a function that gives the CDF of the distribution at a certain point and optimizes it to find where it reaches the randomly generated number:

```
def mytwofunctions():
    def hansenPDF (z,x):
        heta = 2.1+27.9/exp(-x[3])
        c = math.gamma((heta+1)/2)/(sqrt(math.pi*(heta-2))*math.gamma(heta/2))
        a = 4*x[3]*c*(heta-2)/(heta-1)
        b = sqrt(1+3*x[3]**2-a**2)

        if z < -a/b:
            g = b*c*(1+1/(heta-2)*((b*z+a)/(1-x[3]))**2)**(-(heta+1)/2)
        else:
            g = b*c*(1+1/(heta-2)*((b*z+a)/(1+x[3]))**2)**(-(heta+1)/2)

        return g

    def integrator (z):
        return integrate.quad(hansenPDF,-100,z,args=(optimparams[-1]))[0] - random.random()
```

Any ideas to do something more efficient?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Sorry, my question is: is there a faster, less memory-intensive way to find z so that the integral from -100 to z is equal to the randomly generated number?

Comment: Do you have a closed form for the CDF?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. I believe the closed form is quite complex as it uses the hypergeometric function according to wolfram alpha. So I don't know if it could be useful.

Comment: I haven't heard of a "hansen" distribution before, and it's not listed in Devroye's [Non-Uniform Random Variate Generation](http://www.eirene.de/Devroye.pdf) text, nor on Leemis' [distribution chart](http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/chart/UDR/UDR.html).  That pretty much leaves you with trying to derive a closed form CDF so you can do [inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling), or finding easily invertible bounding functions and doing [acceptance/rejection](http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~hwan/IE680/Lectures/Chap08Slides.pdf).

Comment: and `z` is going from -100 to what? Upper limit?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'll have a look at the links and try to find bounding functions!

Comment: @pjs Here it is http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~bhansen/papers/ier_94.pdf, formula (10). Looks like generalization of the t-distribution, which means CDF is expressed via hypergeometric function(s).

Comment: Took a look at this distribution - due to similarity to t-distribution, you might take a look at t-distribution sampling in wiki and elsewhere

Comment: @Habtra you might get more interest in this question at stats.stackexchange.com. Also, try supplying the definitions for a, b, and c, and the ranges for lambda and eta when you try to integrate the pdf; it might help find a simpler answer.